# Installation and integration of the DOJO toolkit

Tags: dojo

How can I install the DOJO toolkit and use it on my website?  Is there a tutorial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

http://docs.dojocampus.org/quickstart/gettingstarted

"Dojo's now included on your page, no install, no fuss." - apparently